# How do I disable skipping chapters with two-finger double taps on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, touch, gestures, multi-touch

When I watch YouTube videos on my ASUS Zenfone 8, if I double tap with one finger to [skip forward 10 seconds](https://www.howtogeek.com/667493/how-to-skip-back-and-forward-10-seconds-in-youtube-and-other-apps/) my input is often misregistered as a two finger tap that [skips to the next chapter](https://www.howtogeek.com/749168/psa-double-tap-youtube-with-2-fingers-to-skip-chapters/). This can result in skipping ahead 1 hour instead of 10 seconds.

Is there a way to disable the two-finger double-tap gesture to skip chapters on YouTube? Or alternatively, is there a way to disable or reduce the sensitivity of two-finger gestures on my device?